# useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I add the Suspense tags to the following code :-

```
"use client";

import { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { Suspense } from 'react'

import Form from "@components/Form";

const UpdatePrompt = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const promptId = searchParams.get("id");

    const [post, setPost] = useState({ prompt: "", tag: "", });
    const [submitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getPromptDetails = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/prompt/${promptId}`);
            const data = await response.json();

            setPost({
                prompt: data.prompt,
                tag: data.tag,
            });
        };

        if (promptId) getPromptDetails();
    }, [promptId]);

    const updatePrompt = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsSubmitting(true);

        if (!promptId) return alert("Missing PromptId!");

        try {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/prompt/${promptId}`, {
                method: "PATCH",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    prompt: post.prompt,
                    tag: post.tag,
                }),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                router.push("/");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } finally {
            setIsSubmitting(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Suspense>
            <Form
                type='Edit'
                post={post}
                setPost={setPost}
                submitting={submitting}
                handleSubmit={updatePrompt}
            />
        </Suspense>
    );
};

export default UpdatePrompt;
```

I tried adding it in the return statement but during deployment in Vercel this error showed :-
Error:
x Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?
,-[/vercel/path0/app/update-prompt/page.jsx:63:1]

Can someone help me in adding the Suspense tags in the above code. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

When using `<UpdatePrompt />`, wrap it in a `<Suspense />` to avoid marking the entire route as dynamic route.

```
import {Suspense} from "react";

// ...

<Suspense>
  <UpdatePrompt />
</Suspense>
```

`<Suspense>` must be outside of the component that uses runtime values (e.g. searchParams). so putting it inside the `UpdatePrompt` component won't work.

### Update

Based on the repo shared in the comments, https://github.com/AnanteshG/Quasar/blob/main/app/update-prompt/page.jsx

The default export of page.jsx is used internally by Next.js to be rendered in the route. Update your code to wrap the UpdatePrompt in a parent component:

```
const Page = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense>
      <UpdatePrompt/>
    </Suspense>
  )
}

export default Page
```

remember to remove `export default UpdatePrompt` line

Comment: But where do I use the <UpdatePrompt /> tag? I have exported it but haven't used anywhere in the code.

Here's the github if it helps :https://github.com/AnanteshG/Quasar

This is the path to the error file : app/update-prompt/page.jsx